# Creating a permutation, with restrictions

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pandas, permutation

I'm using Python, with Pandas and Numpy, though the problem feels like a more generic algorithm design issue.

I have a list (actually an array) of elements, and I want to generate a permutation of that list. However, certain items are not allowed to be in certain positions in the list. I want to generate a permutation that obeys these restrictions. What is an effective way to do this?

My actual use is case is a Pandas data frame, with two columns `X` and `Y`. `X` and `Y` both have the same numbers, in different orders. Numbers are not unique. No number appears in `X` and `Y` in the same row (i.e. no number is matched with itself). I want to permute `Y`, while keeping the restriction that no number is matched with itself. I had been calling Numpy's `permute` on `Y`, but about 1% of the resulting rows have `X==Y`.

Edit with example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1,2],
        [1,4],
        [4,2],
        [2,3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y'],
              data=data)


df_permuted = df.copy()

df_permuted.Y = np.random.permutation(df.Y)

print(df.X==df.Y)
#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3    False
#dtype: bool

print(df_permuted.X==df_permuted.Y)
#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3     True
#dtype: bool
```

Edit: 
The obvious algorithm, which is too slow/doesn't scale, is this:

```
for every row i:  
 define the set of valid candidate "other" rows (where i.X != other.Y and i.Y != other.X)
 grab a row from the valid set
 swap i.Y and other.Y
```

In our Pandas example this would be:

```
from numpy.random import choice
for i in df.index:
    other_rows = df[(df.ix[i].X != df.Y) * (df.ix[i].Y != df.X)]
    selected_row = choice(other_rows.index)
    original_Y = df.ix[i].Y
    df.ix[i].Y = df.ix[selected_row].Y
    df.ix[selected_row].Y = original_Y
print(df.X==df.Y)
#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3    False
#dtype: bool
```

The problem is this is too slow, and not parallelized at all. Is there a way to parallelize it? I imagine the answer is "No", because the swaps made on one row affect what are valid "others" for the next row.

Edit for sense of scale:
About 1.4*10^7 rows, 2*10^6 unique values in X and a similar number in Y. And need to generate about 10^3 independent permutations. I actually take groups of rows and permute their contents independently, and some groups are very small (e.g. 10 rows), but many are rather large (10^5). This buys a bit of help, but in the end there are a lot of rows! Just running a simple `np.random.permutation` on the 10^7 rows takes about 7 seconds, which is sufficient. Running the restricted permutation algorithm above (implemented in numpy instead of pandas for added speed) takes 7 seconds for just 10^3 rows. Eep!

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: Would it be enough to filter out those values after using the `permutation` function?

Comment: Filter how? It could be that the permutation process matches, e.g. all the 2s to each other. Then grabbing only those values where X==Y and permuting them wouldn't solve anything; the resulting permutation is the same set of 2s as before.

Comment: You say "X and Y both have the same numbers, in different orders" but in your example Y doesn't contain 1 and X doesn't contain 3, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I think the problem you have is: X and Y are arbitrary multisets, and you want to come up with pairs such that all the values on one side make up X, on the other make Y, and no value is paired with itself. Is that right?

Comment: And just to be clear - you want any such pairing, you're not trying to choose one fairly or anything.

Comment: @PaulCrowley I believe that is correct. However, the goal is to randomly select these permutations. The goal is to generate many such permutations and describe their statistics. So in that sense we do need to choose "fairly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not coming up with a solution that's too specific to your example. However, if feasible, you might create EVERY permutation then remove the ones that don't match your criteria. Then you could either use that directly or randomly sample from the resulting permutations.

Here's code that is inspired by your example above. I realize I'm using slightly different starting assumptions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( list(itertools.product([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])), columns = ['X','Y'])
print df


    X  Y
0   1  1
1   1  2
2   1  3
3   1  4
4   2  1
5   2  2
6   2  3
7   2  4
8   3  1
9   3  2
10  3  3
11  3  4
12  4  1
13  4  2
14  4  3
15  4  4
```

then set up the criteria you're interested in:

```
print df[df.X != df.Y]

    X  Y
1   1  2
2   1  3
3   1  4
4   2  1
6   2  3
7   2  4
8   3  1
9   3  2
11  3  4
12  4  1
13  4  2
14  4  3
```

***Edit***:
I'll leave all the above combination junk there because someone else might find it useful. But after chatting in the comments I think I have a possible solution.

It seems like you can do the permutation, then break the permuted dataframe into two subsets:

1. data that does not meet criteria (i.e. X==Y)
2. data that does meet criteria (X!=Y)

Then we could take the first subset, and simply permute it again. Subset 1 should be much smaller than subset 2. We just recursively do that and it should be pretty easy and fast to create a set of records that match the criteria.

Of course we'll have to handle the situation where there is only one row that has a match.

I've implemented an example solution:

Set up some play data of similar size to the real data:

```
np.random.seed(3)
n=14000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : np.random.randint(2000000, size=n), 
                   'Y' : np.random.randint(2000000, size=n)})
```

The example data will start with some duplicate rows, but that's OK. Let's create the shuffle function:

```
def permuteDataFrame(inDf):
    permutedDf = pd.DataFrame({'X' : np.random.permutation(inDf.X), 
                               'Y' : np.random.permutation(inDf.Y)})
    # check for dupes
    clash = permutedDf[permutedDf.X == permutedDf.Y] 
    if clash.shape[0] > 1: #repermuting can't work if only one row has a match
        clash = permutedDf[permutedDf.X == permutedDf.Y].copy()
        noclash = permutedDf[permutedDf.X != permutedDf.Y].copy()
        # recursion FTW: run the clashes back through this algo
        clash = permuteDataFrame(clash)
        permutedDf = pd.concat([clash, noclash ])
    if clash.shape[0] == 1: # handle the single match problem
        # solving the single match by grabbing the single match plus a random other record and permuting
        # get the vector of bools that indicate matches
        clashIndex = permutedDf.X == permutedDf.Y
        # randomly make another one True
        ilocToSwap = np.random.randint(permutedDf.shape[0]) # random record location to swap
        indexOfClashes.iloc[ilocToSwap] = True
        clash = permutedDf[indexOfClashes]
        # recursion FTW: run the clashes back through this algo
        clash = permuteDataFrame(clash)
        permutedDf = pd.concat([clash, noclash ])
    return permutedDf
```

On my Mac, a simple permutation takes 5.3 seconds. The new `permuteDataFrame()` function takes 5.8 seconds. Even if it takes 8 seconds on your machine that will get you 1000 in 2.2 hours. That might work.

Comment: That's an interesting start! How would we modify this if we can't enumerate every permutation due to memory limits?

Comment: Just off the top of my head: 1) permute subsets 2) build a loop to permute and check conditions then write out the results to a file. That way only one condition is in memory at a time. If you want random results later you could open the file, count rows, randomly select a row. I guess it depends on the use case.

Comment: I just read the added comments on your question and I suspect you're getting answers that don't help because the answerers are having trouble groking the scale of your problem. Can you share the order of magnitude of the problem somehow? Is the real problem 100 variables with 30 values each? 1000 x 300? 100 x 3e10? I think the answer really is bounded by your scale.

Comment: yeah, my answer of 'calculate them all' is not right for your problem. And doing a loop is too slow. So somehow we need to formulate this as a numpy problem to get the benefit of numpy speed. Calculate then test using numpy logic somehow?

Comment: The issue I'm looking at is that it doesn't seem that it can be parallelized, for the reasons given in the post. Your thought is to generate possible permutations and test if they work? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Iterating rows is slow... Always. But I can't think of how to write a permute function that meets your criteria using numpy vectorization. Possibly something that could be done in cython or C?

Comment: What would be a way to test that it is actually the row iteration factor that is the slowing things down?  Also, I misspoke: By "parallelization" I meant "vectorization". Doesn't the reliance of row i on the output of row i-1 mean it can't be vectorized, and there must always be iteration?

Comment: Yes, my intuition is that the i-1 dependance limits vectorization. Keep in mind that vectorization still does loops, but it does them in native C code instead of Python. I'd be inclined to test Numba to see what order of magnitude gains you could get. If I'm reading your question right, you only need 1000 permutations out of a VERY large possible set of solutions.

Comment: Just tried using Numba and Numpy's `vectorize`. Neither resulted in a speed up. In fact, they both had some slow down >_>

Comment: I added an attempt to my answer above. Is that in the ballpark?

Comment: and by 'attempt' I mean I created an algo that, I think, solves your problem by selecting out the problem children and shaking them up. Wow. That sounds violent.

Comment: Thanks! This was a route suggested earlier, that probably typically works in most cases. However, what will this do when there are a set of >1 rows remaining that are all the same number? Permuting that subset won't make them fit the requirement. Won't it run forever?

Comment: That's a really good corner solution I didn't think of. One way to handle that is to check for that condition and just randomly add more records to the mix if you have that condition. Not unlike how the set==1 condition is handled.

Comment: One really naive way to handle things would be to test for clash then, if clash exists, always add an additional 100 records at random to the `clash` dataset which then gets permuted again. That way no chance of n=1 and almost no chance of ending up with all values the same (assuming a large number of unique values, which I think you have)

Comment: Thanks JD! I'm going to mark this as accepted. What you've suggested is probably much faster than the other implementation, for most datasets (certainly mine). We should note that it can probably still behave pathologically for really adversarial data. For example, what if the original data is the _only_ configuration that works? Then this implementation will have problems. I am antsy in general of anything that re-rolls dice, even ever smaller sets of dice, hoping it converges to a solution. But for now I will stop worrying and learn to love the re-roll. Thanks!

Comment: I agree that this solution is very bespoke for your situation. good luck. This was a fun brain teaser ;)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do what you're doing (permuting Y) but then at the end just check to make sure nothing matches:

```
if (df.X == df.Y).any():
    reject_dataframe()
```

Comment: If having bad rows was vanishingly unlikely, then that could work. However, NOT having bad rows is vanishingly unlikely. In my use case, I say "about 1% of the resulting rows have X==Y." So just rerolling the dice until I get a valid result will take eons.

Comment: oh, i TOTALLY misread that. i thought you were saying 1% of dataframes, not rows. yeah, this would take a long time, sorry about that.